# AWS Step Function: How to get the last element of a StringSplit?

Tags: aws-step-functions

Given

```
{
  "myStringArray.$": "States.StringSplit('this.is.a.test', '.')"
}
```

I would like to get the last element of the array generated by the split, so in that case `test`. I was looking at `States.ArrayGetItem(..)` but before I would need the `.length()`. Any help?

Comment: Have you tried using `States.ArrayLength`? Something like `States.ArrayGetItem(States.StringSplit('this.is.a.test', '.'), States.MathAdd(States.ArrayLength(States.StringSplit('this.is.a.test', '.')), -1)` - obviously did not try it myself and as you might already see and guess: this is not *really* feasible. Such logic needs to be encapsulated within your individual step function steps, e.g. lambda functions instead of within the step function itself.

Comment: Yes that was my same conclusion, the reason why I asked it is that requires 2 times the split. So I am wondering if there is a better way to do so.

Answer (score 3):

✅ @luk2302's nested intrinsic function works:

GIVEN:

```json
{
  "Comment": "Pick the last element of a split string",
  "StartAt": "Split",
  "States": {
    "Split": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Parameters": {
        "lastElement.$": "States.ArrayGetItem(States.StringSplit($.inputString, '.'), States.MathAdd(States.ArrayLength(States.StringSplit($.inputString, '.')), -1))"
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

WHEN input is `{"inputString: "this.is.a.test"}`

THEN output is:

```json
{
  "lastElement": "test"
}
```

---

❌ Using a `-1` index to get last element directly does not work:

```json
"States.ArrayGetItem(States.StringSplit($.inputString, '.'), -1)"
```

Runtime error: `Invalid arguments in States.ArrayGetItem`

Comment: Thanks for this. Was pulling my hair out for awhile.